# AJAX request always return false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actually, I'm doing a simple php form with some AJAX.
I've tried to solve the error by myself, but can't figure out what I'm missing.

The result is always false, no record are done in the database too

The form :

```
<form id="signUpForm" action="" method="POST"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="pseudoUp" placeholder="pseudo"></div>
  <div><input type="password" name="passwordUp" placeholder="password"></div>
  <div><input type="submit" name="signUpForm" value="signup"></div>
  <div class="signUpMsg"></div>
</form>
```

The php scripts :

config.php :

```
<?php

session_start();

  define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('MYSQL_USER', ' ');
  define('MYSQL_PASSWD', ' ');
  define('MYSQL_DB', 'php');

  try {
    $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWD);
    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```

signUp.php:

```
<?php

  require_once 'config.php';

  if($_POST["lastname"] != "" && $_POST["firstname"] != "" && $_POST["pseudo"] != ""  && $_POST["password"] != ""){
    $req = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO users (lastname, firstname, pseudo, password) VALUES(:lastname, :firstname, :pseudo, :password)");
    $req->bindValue(':lastname', $_POST["lastname"]);
    $req->bindValue(':firstname', $_POST["firstname"]);
    $req->bindValue(':pseudo', $_POST["pseudo"]);
    $req->bindValue(':password', sha1($_POST["password"]));
    if ($req->execute()){
      echo 1;
    }else{
      echo 2;
    }
  }

?>
```

and finally, the AJAX:

```
$(function(){
  $('#signUpForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Undo mistake, thank to @apokryfos
    data = {
        lastname : $("input[name='lastname']").val(),
        firstname : $("input[name='firstname']").val(),
        pseudo : $("input[name='pseudo']").val(),
        password : $("input[name='password']").val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
      method : "POST",
      url : "php/signUp.php",
      data : data,
      success : function(res){
        if(res == 1){
          $('.signUpMsg').html('Sign up done !');
        }else{
          $('.signUpMsg').html('Sign up fail');
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Thanx for reading !

EDIT :

The error came from a wrong way to get the data (No id in the input, while checking for input id's in AJAX) and an input name conflict in the same page. Also I changed the 'echo true/false' in signIn.php to 'echo 1/2' as mentionned by Apokryfos.

Thank for your help !!

Comment: is database username is empty

Comment: You should not roll your own password hashing. Here's a good article about why `sha*`-functions aren't suitable for password hashing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88951/store-password-using-sha1. You should really use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when working with passwords.

Comment: Other than that, have you checked your error log for any errors?

Comment: 1) check console 2) use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page 3) print post'd data before use 4) allows query errors (not `echo true; / echo false;`) and then we'll have more information to deal with

Comment: All the rows are empties after the submit, and the logs seems to be clean. Also I've tried to do the request in PHP and it works. I'm gonna try to use password_hash() and tell you the resut.

Comment: Check what's in the `$_POST` variable. As it stands now you're going to be getting a `false` result either when the insert fails **or** when one of the required post fields is empty. In the latter case there's not going to be any error thrown either.

Comment: AFTER AJAX DATA FIX | I've checked if the data were correct, with console.log(data); , and figure out that the pseudo and password were empty, may I check this

Comment: Ok, the empty value come from a second form (SignIn in this case) with the same input name. Junior mistake here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're building your post data in the wrong way, `#something` means the DOM element with **id** `something`. You need to use the input `name` attribute:

```
data = {
  lastname : $("input[name='lastname']").val(),
  firstname : $("input[name='firstname']").val(),
  pseudo : $("input[name='pseudo']").val(),
  password : $("input[name='password']").val(),
}
```

I will also suggest something additional. Use HTTP codes instead of returning a number (That's what the codes are there for and they are universally understood):

```
if($_POST["lastname"] != "" && $_POST["firstname"] != "" && $_POST["pseudo"] != ""  && $_POST["password"] != ""){
    $req = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO users (lastname, firstname, pseudo, password) VALUES(:lastname, :firstname, :pseudo, :password)");
    $req->bindValue(':lastname', $_POST["lastname"]);
    $req->bindValue(':firstname', $_POST["firstname"]);
    $req->bindValue(':pseudo', $_POST["pseudo"]);
    $req->bindValue(':password', sha1($_POST["password"]));
    if ($req->execute()){
      echo 1;
    }else{
      http_response_code(500); //server error
      echo 2;
    }
  }
  http_response_code(400); //Client error (didn't send the correct fields)
```

And the JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
  method : "POST",
  url : "php/signUp.php",
  data : data,
  success : function(res){
      $('.signUpMsg').html('Sign up done !'); //Only runs this when successful
  },
  error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
      if (xhr.status == 500) { 
         $('.signUpMsg').html('Sign up fail');
      } else if (xhr.status == 400) {
         $('.signUpMsg').html('Please fill the form properly');
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Good catch! I totally missed that small, but crucial, part.

Comment: EDIT: UV on that nice catch ^^

Comment: Damn that's a huge mistake I've done here, thank for pointing it out. And thanks for giving me the proper way to get the data. But it ain't fix the whole code

Comment: @AoNoLoki If this answer helped you, you should accept it.

Comment: use others tips from comments, and if any other identified errors, post another question maybe ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Done, I was working around the tips of OldPadawan to get more ressource  about the error

Comment: @AoNoLoki as I mentioned you'd be getting a "falsey" response in the case that the required `$_POST` data was not there. That's because JavaScript would interpret the blank response as a false (which is what `echo false` actually does too), so you'd get a `false`response but no errors at all.

Comment: @apokryfos Very usefull tips here, I ain't know this about JS. I've changed that for 'echo <digit>' to get a cleaner code.

Comment: @AoNoLoki I've suggested an alternative as an update.

Comment: @apokryfos A looooot of thanks for this suggestion, I've asked for this many times to my trainer but he keep doing it without the error statement. Also  sending the exact error message is very usefull and give a better view on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

in ajax part you are using input id like this

```
data = {
      lastname : $('#lastname').val(),
      firstname : $('#firstname').val(),
      pseudo : $('#pseudo').val(),
      password : $('#password').val(),
    }
```

but in input there is no id for inputs

```
<div><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="pseudo" placeholder="pseudo"></div>
  <div><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"></div>
```